# Most efficient way to rasterize a planet

Tags: spatial-database

I'm working on a Webservice where GIS supports my services as a Crowd Intelligence Aggregator to help civilian (like civilized) aid to support provisioners in a case of emergency, e.g. pestilence, military/civil conflict or other natural planet-bound catastrophies like earthquakes.

Example:
I imagine, that a convoy tries to support folks with vaccines. So it has to decide, whether it drives one road or a parched stream bed. My planned open source service will tell via visible heatmap, whether it may pass easily to its destination via stream bed, or it's likely to be attacked by brigands (where it happened the past weeks) on the road though noticed and announced to the webservice.

To rasterize the planet I'm thinking of how to store local gathered information on a map/datawarehouse as a synonym for fast predictive information analysis. The tiles shall be a tetragon or pentagon. The goal is with regard to calculate a - heatmap. Maybe it's harder to tesseract a pentagon than an tetragon... Maybe you folks have experience or knowlegde to help me? I'm not sure what's "better"...

Comment: From the GIS point of view rectangular or square tiles are easiest, as that is how the raster is stored, to use an irregular shape such as hexagon, pentagon.. you will need to have NoData outside the image area - essentially wasted space. If you're intending to cover the entire globe as one dataset then you will need to use a geographic spatial reference (WGS84 springs to mind) but layers like open street map use web mercator. This is an ambitious project,  good luck with it.